# Need help installing/using Netgear WNA3100 wireless adapter on Lubuntu on 16.04 i686/i386

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, lubuntu

I've been trying to get my wifi working on an old netbook (HP Mini 110) which originally came with a Broadcom BCM 4312. After various attempts to get it working, getting the right driver, fine tuning etc, it seems that wifi card just won't work right. At least it doesn't have the connection reliability or speed I would like. I think it's just too old now.

So, I gave up and went out and bought a wifi adapter. Namely, the Netgear WNA3100 (https://www.netgear.com/support/product/WNA3100?cid=wmt_netgear_organic).

Now, when I plugged it in, my Lubuntu distribution only detected it and did nothing else.

My question is, how do I install the proper drivers for that wifi adapter and get Lubuntu to look and use that as the default card to connect to networks. I would also like to disable the built-in wifi card, the BCM 4312, so it doesn't take up unnecessary power.

I've installed the `firmmware-b43-installer` package as per my discussion here: [Wifi displays but won't connect on Lubuntu 16.04 i686/i386](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874306/wifi-displays-but-wont-connect-on-lubuntu-16-04-i686-i386) If that helps.

Finally, I ran `lsusb` on the netbook with the adapter connected and got the following information about the adapter:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231]
```

---

===**EDIT**===

I'm open to suggestions making use of package `ndiswrapper`.

Also, I had mistyped the product name, I've corrected that now.

Comment: Can you return the Netgear adapter?  I would replace the Broadcom internal adapter with an Intel 7260 if the Intel is available in the same profile as the broadcom

Comment: @Jeremy31 I'm not sure I can manage installing an internal card. I'd like to keep this adapter if possible or switch it out for a more compatible one from Best Buy. I was thinking I'll just blacklist the b43 drivers and install the windows drivers using ndiswrapper according to this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper Do you think that's a good idea?

Comment: I had that card and tried many things, even with ndiswrapper and windows drivers it had issues so I mailed it to chili555 and he didn't have much better luck.  Look online to see what best buy has in stock locally and search for the model number and linux to get an idea if they work

Comment: @Jeremy31 I got it working with the driver on this page http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WNA3100 and ndiswrapper. But now I'm concerned, was it safe getting a driver from someplace online?

Comment: That site should be as safe as any