# Wi-Fi Adapter refusing to work! (Netgear WNA3100)

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, internet, broadcom

I'm a complete and utter Ubuntu noob (and Linux in general). I installed the OS last night, and had this issue, and decided to sleep on it, woke up and have been working for 2 hours to no avail. My Wi-Fi adapter, a Netgear WNA3100 refuses to work. It shows up when I run `lnusb` and I see 
`Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0846:9020 Netgear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231]` so it is clearly connected to my PC. I have successfully installed the "Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2" drivers using ndiswrapper version 1.61, but it still won't even show up anywhere.

I know the drivers are installed because it says: `ndiswrapper -l
bcmn43xx32 : driver installed
        device (0846:9020) present
bcmn43xx64 : driver installed
        device (0846:9020) present`

However, when I run lshw, the device is not there. Only:

    `lshw -c network
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
     vendor: Qualcom Atheros
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
     logical name: enp2s0
     version: 10
     serial: 78:e3:b5:c7:a5:34
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
     resources: irq:35 memory:fe200000-fe23ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
*-network DISABLED
     description: Wireless interface
     product: RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
     vendor: Ralink corp.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
     logical name: wlp5s0
     version: 00
     serial: 70:18:8b:80:a9:96
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.8.0-36-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
     resources: irq:19 memory:fe100000-fe10ffff`

That second one is a device that I disabled. It is a built in antenna that has never worked. It will show the networks but it will not connect, which is nothing new, as it doesn't work on Windows either.

I forgot to mention that I am dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows 10, and this adapter DOES work on Windows 10.

When I run iwconfig, I get this:

    `iwconfig
lo          no wireless extensions.
enp2s0      no wireless extensions.
wlp5so      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
            Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated    Tx-Power=0 dBm
            Retry short limit:7  RTS thr:off  Fragment thr:off
            Power Management:off`

I have been trying for such a long time, and I am quite lost on what to do next. I have scavenged Google for hours looking for an answer, following what seems like 100 guides on what to do, and am just lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you need any more information, just let me know.

However, please note that I will not be able to use internet on this Ubuntu machine. Buying another adapter is not currently an option, and the desktop is located on the other side of my home to the WiFi Router, so ethernet is also not an option. I had to type in all of those code snippets by hand, so excuse typos. Also, as a final note, it is not a range issue, because, as aforementioned, the adapter works fine and I get a solid 100mbps on Windows 10.

Any and all help would be appreciated, and I'm hoping some of you geniuses on here can help me out, and end my headache trying to wrap my head around this problem.

Thank you all,

Regards,

Johnny.

Comment: Did you by chance Google up this? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=wna3100

Comment: @chili555 I had in fact attempted to follow that guide, but after following the steps, I got to "The balloon at Network Manager notified me that I had available networks and I tried to connect. After a couple of tries, I connected and even at N speeds! After about an hour, it slowed and stopped. Even though it appeared to be connected, pings to my router or to the DNS nameserver 8.8.8.8 went unanswered." And, surprise! There were no networks, and clicking the WiFi symbol simply results in:  "Wi-Fi Networks device not managed"

Comment: That was not the part to which I wished to draw your attention. It was this: " I don't believe this device can be made to work correctly in Ubuntu 14.04 and later. Please don't ask me to help. I've tried everything I know of and it doesn't work."

Comment: @chili555 Oh. So it's a lost cause then? Should I just go back to Windows and accept my defeat? As mentioned in the original post, buying another adapter is not an option at this time unfortunately.

Comment: While I see some things we might address, even if we embarked on a long process to fix them, ultimately, it will not work. It is not *your* defeat because Broadcom haven't provided Linux drivers for this otherwise good device. Several of us have tried hard to get the well known bcmn43xx64 to work and it just won't. If you are in a dual-boot situation, I'd just wait until the budget allows the purchase of a better adapter. I am sorry I have no other suggestions.

Comment: @chili555 Very well. Thank you so much for at least looking at my problem, I really appreciate it! Hopefully I can delve into the world of linux soon!

Comment: I hope so, too. I look forward to seeing you again soon.

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem with this wifi adapter, I got it working with ndiswrapper: http://askubuntu.com/questions/878129/need-help-installing-using-netgear-wna3100-wireless-adapter-on-lubuntu-on-16-04  See the comments. Just make sure you know what you're doing and follow this guide for ndiswrapper: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper Also, you might have to undo any changes you've made to your system following the previous guides, although that might not be necessary depending on what you've done so far.

Comment: And since you need packages from the internet just download them on a flash drive or save them on windows 10 on that machine and copy from linux. Just be sure to unmount the windows partition after you're done copying the files.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out this driver at https://github.com/Elycin/linux-wna3100-install

[image]